# How to assign escape as key equivalent to a button in swift?

Tags: swift

I've got working code in objective c class which is like follows :

```
closeButton.keyEquivalent = @"\e";
```

This does not work in swift, as it says "Invalid escape sequence in literal."
I've tried to use the following code:

```
closeButton.keyEquivalent = "\u{53}"
```

But also no luck. Any ideas ?

Comment: The correct key code for escape would be u{1b} but that does not work either. Probably escape is caught in NSResponder somewhere else. E.g. if focus is on a dropdown it opens the menu.

Comment: @NickCatib yeah double checked now, does not work with \\e

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to assign

```
closeButton.keyEquivalent = "\u{1b}"
```

Just tried in a test app.

**Edit**: According to @Lucasware's comment the ObjC assignment is

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 0x1b]
```

Comment: How do I do this in objective c?

Comment: Thanks but I figured it out = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 0x1b];

Answer (score -1):

Thanks this code working fine to close window when click on esc key

```
standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.keyEquivalent = "\u{1b}"
```

Comment: Please explain the additional insight which your post contributes to existing answers (especially https://stackoverflow.com/a/28541684/7733418 ). The core of the implementation seems to be very similar. Please make the relevant difference more obvious and point out its advantages. See [answer] and [edit] accordingly. Otherwise your posts reads too much like "thanks", which is not considered an answer on StackOverflow and risks being flagged and deleted as "not an answer".